# how to use if condition inside data-bind tag to include attr tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

`data-bind="text: slottext() , attr : {title: Label}"`

If label is null then i don't want to show attr tag include in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout does this for you. When you set `Label` to `null`, it doesn't blindly add `title: "null"` to  your element, it actually removes the attribute.

You can see this behaviour in the source code:

> ```
> // To cover cases like "attr: { checked:someProp }", we want to remove the attribute entirely
> // when someProp is a "no value"-like value (strictly null, false, or undefined)
> // (because the absence of the "checked" attr is how to mark an element as not checked, etc.)
>
> var toRemove = (attrValue === false) || (attrValue === null) || (attrValue === undefined);
> if (toRemove)
>   element.removeAttribute(attrName);
> ```

[source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/attr.js#L11)

So, the other way around, if you ever *want* to put `null` or `false` in a `data-` attribute, make sure to call `JSON.stringify` on the value.

This code in action in an example:

```js
var vm = {
  text: "Text",
  label: ko.observable("label")
};


ko.applyBindings(vm);

var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

console.log("With label:");
console.log(wrapper.innerHTML);

console.log("Without label:");
vm.label(null);
console.log(wrapper.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div data-bind="text: text, attr: { title: label }"></div>
</div>
```